# CImage::Load() from memory without using CreateStreamOnHGlobal

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, atl

I am displaying a live view video from camera. Every frame I download into a byte array (pImageData) which I have to allocate.

Now, to display, I am using a CImage (MFC). 
However, all samples I find are based on using GlobalAlloc, yet another memcpy and CreateStreamOnHGlobal.

I'd like to avoid doing another allocation/deallocation and memory copy. Each frame is over 2mb and I am pushing 30 fps!

Is it possible to create an IStream on non-HGLOBAL based memory?
OR
Is it somehow possible to coerce Image::Load() to work with byte array?

Here is the code:

```
// pImageData is an array with bytes, size is the sizeOfThatArray

CComPtr<IStream> stream;

HGLOBAL hMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GHND, size);
LPVOID pBuff = ::GlobalLock(hMem);

memcpy(pBuff, pImageData, size); // <-- would like to avoid this

::GlobalUnlock(hMem);

CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem, TRUE, &stream); // <-- or create stream on non-hglobal memory

CImage image;
image.Load(stream); // <-- Or load directly from pImageData

// .. display image

image.Destroy();

::GlobalFree(hMem);
```

Comment: What format is your image data in the byte array? Is it a bitmap? Does it have any headers?

Comment: You can create an `IStream` on anything you like. It's a only the interface that's defined, you can actually implement the methods however you want.

Comment: @o_wiseman - I am not 100% sure, its raw data from DSLR viewfinder. My guess is that its a plain bitmap, considering that nothing is done to the data itself during all this GlobalLock/memcpy chain of operations.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, thanks, I know that but it seems like a lot of yak shaving for a seemingly simple task. Any pointers to an implementation I might consult?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Hans, Perfect! Tried and it works, and the code is cleaner (though not sure if internally there is still an overhead of copy). If you post this as an answer - I'll mark as a solution.

Comment: There is no copy.  Just create your own post, show how you used it, and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm confused how that helps, since `SHCreateMemStream` is doing the copy internally that you were hoping to avoid.

Comment: Yeah, documentation is not clear whether there is an internal copy or not. All it says "The contents of this (passed as param) buffer are used to set the initial contents of the memory stream." So, is there?

Comment: If it didn't copy the data, the docs would have to make clear that the original memory needs to remain valid until the last reference on the `IStream` is released. They don't say anything of the sort, so it's clear that a copy takes place internally.

Comment: `Every frame I download into a byte array (pImageData) which I have to allocate` Why not allocate *that* buffer with `GlobalAlloc + GlobalLock` since you know you'll need an HGLOBAL in the end? At least, there would be no redundant copy that way.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Hans for pointing out SHCreateMemStream, which I did not know existed.
The code is much cleaner, but still unsure whether SHCreateMemStream creates a copy internally (documentation is unclear)

[edit] As per Jonathan' comments, looks like it still has to make a copy internally. Dang ..

Final code

```
// pImageData is an array with bytes, size is the sizeOfThatArray

// Still not clear if this is making a copy internally
IStream* pMemStream = SHCreateMemStream(pImageData, size);

CComPtr<IStream> stream;

stream.Attach(pMemStream); // Need to Attach, otherwise ownership is not transferred and we leak memory

CImage image;
image.Load(stream); 

// .. display image

image.Destroy();

// No need for further cleanup, CComPtr does the job
```

Comment: just linking this i found since it's relevant to the "Need to Attach" comment [The difference between assignment and attachment with ATL smart pointers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091120-00/?p=15953) of course if you also want, you can manually `stream->Release();` without using `CComPtr`